# How are dynamic segments in Google Analytics retroactive?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Are dynamic advanced segments retroactive at the session or visitor level? Can it retroactively recalculate session data or can it retroactively recalculate visitor data?

Here is an example as this is a foggy question.

Say I add an event tag to GA today. Tomorrow i run a report where the dynamic segment is for visitors who have triggered the event. The report requests unique visitors over time.

Now, if it is retroactive at the visitor level, the visitor is now tagged as having triggered the event. The report should show data going back in time (assuming these are not first time visitors). In this scenario GA will see if the visitors tagged arrived 2 days ago even though the events did not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer no longer reflects up to date information.*

Advanced Segments are not queried at the visitor level, and are thus not able to query data across sessions. They query particular sessions (or, visits), not visitors.

So, if you visit the site today, trigger an event, and then visit the site again tomorrow and don't trigger the event, an advanced segment for that event will be a query that says "Show me all sessions in which this event was trigger"; the former will be included and the latter excluded.

Similarly, if you do an advanced segment for a particular page, what you're saying is "Filter down to all the sessions in which this page was viewed" (this can be confusing for people who apply an advanced segment for a particular page, and the result contains more than just that page.)

However, they are dynamic and can be applied to the retroactively. In other words, the results of the advanced segmentation are not contingent on when the advanced segment itself was created. (This stands in contrasts to, say, account filters, that do not apply themselves retroactively.) They tend to be calculated on the fly; you'll notice that complex advanced segments can often take a long time to process, and tend to increase the likelihood that Google Analytics will return sampled (or, "fast access") data.

There is no way to use advanced segmentation to query *across* sessions.

Comment: I had a hunch. It's a shame, that would be a VERY powerful tool. Thanks!

Comment: Advanced segments now claims it can filter on users rather than sessions, for conditions and sequences.   But that is not what it *actually* does, in the sense of cross session filtering.   Perhaps that functionality can be realised through injecting a UID.    Or on a case by case basis, via injecting a custom dimension.  However the UID injection seems to create a different view of the dataset, rather than being fundamentally integrated.